# Error while compiling gcc4.8.5 for freebsd 11 : error: unknown type name 'choke'

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, gcc

Steps to reproduce the error on a new Ubuntu 14.04 machine.

1. Get include and lib folders from /usr of a previously installed freebsd machine.
2. Set up the folder in the home directory of the ubuntu machine.

Now, the commands to run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc g++ freebsd-buildutils gobjc++-mingw-w64-x86-64 gobjc++-mingw-w64-i686 gobjc++ flex bison libisl-dev libelf-dev binutils-dev libc6-dev linux-libc-dev build-essential
sudo apt-get install zip unzip
sudo apt-get install cloog-isl libcloog-isl-dev ppl-dev libspice-client-glib-2.0-dev
sudo apt-get install gawk mawk patch
sudo mkdir /opt/cross-freebsd && sudo chown -R $USER /opt/cross-freebsd
sudo mkdir build-tmp && cd build-tmp
pushd .
cd ~
cp -a include/. /opt/cross-freebsd/x86_64-pc-freebsd10/
cp -a lib/. /opt/cross-freebsd/x86_64-pc-freebsd10/lib/
ls /opt/cross-freebsd/x86_64-pc-freebsd10/
popd
pushd .
cd /opt/cross-freebsd/x86_64-pc-freebsd10/lib
ln -s libm.so.5 libm.so
ln -s libc.so.7 libc.so
popd
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/binutils-2.25.1.tar.gz
tar xf binutils-2.25.1.tar.gz 
cd binutils-2.25.1/
./configure --enable-libssp --enable-gold --enable-ld \
  --target=x86_64-pc-freebsd10 --prefix=/opt/cross-freebsd
fmake -j4
fmake install
cat config.log | grep -in error
```

Expected : No error

Result :

```
77:Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudflap --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
82:gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
83:gcc: fatal error: no input files
87:gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
88:gcc: fatal error: no input files
137:Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudflap --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
142:g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
143:g++: fatal error: no input files
147:g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
148:g++: fatal error: no input files
238:conftest.c:15:5: error: unknown type name 'choke'
740:stage2_werror_flag=''
```

What can I do to avoid these errors?

Comment: perhaps you use an already existing "config.cache" invalid for you ? Before to launch _configure_ delete all the existing "config.cache" files

Comment: There is no config.cache in binutils-2.25.1
There is config.guess config.log config-ml.in config.rpath config.status config.sub

Comment: You run _configure_ so that produces a _config.cache_, or as I suspected you had an other before and _configure_ did not produced makefiles adapted to your case. The problem is the `grep error` mask the other messages of the log, so it it not possible to see what was happening

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. What are you saying that I should do? BTW, it's a fresh system with only command run before was $sudo apt-get update. That's it. Newly loaded ubuntu system with these commands run atop it.

Comment: Again, doing `cat config.log | grep -in error` you mask all except the lines containing 'error', you only give us the lines 77 then from 82. To give all the first 82 lines of the log could allow us to help you.

Comment: things written onto screen after running ./configure... command : https://pastebin.com/Ydswshym

Comment: Config.log : https://pastebin.com/vkeXbRe2

Comment: With the context I can see these 'errors' are normal, do not give them the importance they don't have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What can I do to avoid these errors?

you cannot, and these errors are not effective but just come from the way *configure* does to establish in which configuration you are.

For instance to check if the version of CLooG is 0.17.0 or not it compiles the a file containing :

```
#include "cloog/version.h"
int
main ()
{
#if CLOOG_VERSION_MAJOR != 0     || CLOOG_VERSION_MINOR != 17     || CLOOG_VERSION_REVISION < 0
     choke me
    #endif
   ;
   return 0;
 }
```

to have an error when compiling indicates `CLOOG_VERSION_MAJOR != 0 || CLOOG_VERSION_MINOR != 17 || CLOOG_VERSION_REVISION < 0` is true. In that case the error is due to `choke me` but it could come from any other invalid form. To not have an error when compiling indicates the version is 0.17.0, to have an error indicates the version is not 0.17.0, that is all.

etc

So finally all is ok

Comment: The report on cloog : https://pastebin.com/GuYtcihz
I can't find the conftest.h, so... I don't think I can edit that file

Comment: @JarvisPennyworth these 'errors' are **not** failure, there are a way to detect your configuration, do not modify files, do not try to remove these 'errors'

Comment: It fails the whole gcc compilation tho... https://pastebin.com/XZHsAUkr

Comment: @JarvisPennyworth I do not see error/failure looking at the link https://pastebin.com/XZHsAUkr